# Are static resources loaded via api like read.csv refreshed during each microbatch when a stream-static join is done in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Are static resources loaded via api like read.csv refreshed during each microbatch when a stream-static join is done in spark.

```
var a = sparkSession.read.csv(directory).as[A] 
var b = sparkSession.readStream... # kafka stream
a.join(b, expr("some expre"), "inner") # Will the changes in  directory made after the spark run started. be reflected in the join? Or is it completely static.
```

Why I am asking this question is because in some cases I have seen the data from static resources are also refreshed. But couldn't justify why it is refreshed during a run.

I couldn't find anything around this in the documentation.

Comment: add `.cache` if you want them "static"

Comment: So you mean static sources (like a, in the above example) are also refreshed during each micro batch?